# The number of distinct pairs of integers $(m,n)$ satisfying $|1+mn|<| m+n|<5$ is?

Tags: inequality, contest-math

$|1+mn|<5$
$\Rightarrow -6 < mn < 4$

$|m+n|<5$
$\Rightarrow -5<m+n<5$

Now as $m$ and $n$ are integers , I tried to make cases such the product of $mn$ is equal to $-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2$ and $3$ as $ -6 < mn < 4$ but I end up getting too many pairs and also I am confused what to do in the case where $mn=0$.

Comment: If $mn = 0$, you still have the restriction that $|m + n| < 5$, which limits the number of ordered pairs that satisfy both conditions.

Comment: Do you mean too many pairs to count easily, or too many pairs according to the official solution? If the latter: what _is_ the official solution?

Comment: @TonyK : Let's say for $mn=3$ then we can have pairs as $(1,3),(3,1),(-1,-3),(-3,-1)$ and all these pairs satisfy the condition $-5<m+n<5$ too. So we have $4$ pairs in this case already and likewise for other cases. The official solution given is $12$.
Similary $4$ pairs for $mn=2$, $2$ pairs for $mn=-1$ and so on.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig: I thought so too at first, then I realised that I was ignoring the condition $|1+mn|<|m+n|$ (as Ganit seems to have done in their comment).

Comment: Ganit, we actually have $|1+mn|<4$, because $|m+n|\le 4$.

Answer (score 3):

The official solution is right: There are 12 solutions:

- (-4, 0)
- (-3, 0)
- (-2, 0)
- (0, -4)
- (0, -3)
- (0, -2)
- (0, 2)
- (0, 3)
- (0, 4)
- (2, 0)
- (3, 0)
- (4, 0)

Comment: How did you arrive at this?

Comment: @Ganit: Brute force.

Answer (score 3):

In what follows, $M$ and $N$ denote $|m|$ and $|n|$ respectively (otherwise we get an unreadable mess of vertical bars).

- If $m,n$ are both non-zero and have the same sign, then $|1+mn|=1+MN$ and $|m+n|=M+N$. So we have
  $$1+MN < M+N$$
  $$\therefore MN-M-N+1<0$$
  $$\therefore (M-1)(N-1)<0$$
  So either $M-1$ or $N-1$ must be $<0$, which is impossible if $M>0$ and $N>0$.
- If $m$ and $n$ are both non-zero and have different signs, we may suppose without loss of generality that $M>N$. So $|1+mn|=MN-1$, and $|m+n|=M-N$, and we have
  $$MN-1<M-N$$
  $$\therefore MN-M+N-1<0$$
  $$\therefore (M+1)(N-1)<0$$
  which is again impossible if $M>0$ and $N>0$.

Therefore one of $m,n$ must be zero!

Answer (score 1):

Another way to get rid of the absolute values is to square:

$|1+mn|^2<|m+n|^2<5^2\implies (1+mn)^2<(m+n)^2<25$ $\implies$ $1<m^2+n^2-m^2n^2\implies0<(n^2-1)(1-m^2)$. Now if $n^2\ge 2$ then we should have $m=0\implies n^2<25\implies n=|2|,|3|,|4|$. Due to symmetricality we also have $n=0$ and $m=|2|,|3|,|4|$. Last we can check that these 12 pairs of integers are really solutions.